# Saving an image to a newly created folder with Uri?

Tags: image, file, uri

The app i am creating is supposed to save a picture in a sub folder of the pictures folder. As long as i save the picture to the base folder it works fine, but it returns an error as soon as i try to target the subfolder. Permission for writing/reading external storage are given. Do i need to create the folder another way to use it? How do i get the URI of the folder itself?
The error for v1 is: "Failed to write destination file".
The error for v2 is: "Unknown or unsupported URL:content://media/external/images/media/ProxF/"

```
private  void captureImage(ImageCapture imageCapture)
{
    //Folder
    File dir = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES) +"/ProxF");

    try{
        if(dir.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   
    //MEDIA API

    String FotoString="picture1";
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, FotoString);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

    

    //Saving to the picture folder - working
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    //V1 - not working
    File folder = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/ProxF/");
    Uri uri1=Uri.fromFile(folder);

    //V2 - not working
    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI+"/ProxF/")


    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions fileOptions= new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(getContentResolver(),uri,contentValues).build();
    imageCapture.takePicture(fileOptions, Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(KameraAc.this, "Image Saved ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            startCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(KameraAc.this, "Failed to save: "+exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            startCamera();
        }
    });

}
```